# MongoDB - Cloning multiple documents with small changes

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, clone

I'm using Mongo DB via the Mongo DB C# driver.

I have a collection with many documents, where each document has an ID and a version. The documents are quite heavy.

I have a scenario where I need to clone multiple documents, and for each I need to increment the version and perform another small change.

The straight forward solution is to load each document into memory, change it in the C# code and insert the new document.

The problem is that performance is not good, since each document is loaded,  deserialized, serialized and saved.
Is there a more optimized way of doing this on the DB side without loading into memory?

I read about the 'out' aggregation stage which can output aggregated documents into an existing collection. Can this possibly be used for this matter?

Edit: another possible option is stored JavaScript, which as I understand is usually not recommended, but this may be a suitable scenario. Would this be a good way to go?

Comment: I'm afraid $out cannot be used here since it effectively replaces existing collection with the output of an aggregation. There is no "append" mode yet unfortunately

Comment: Yes, now I've read that it will only be available in Mongo DB 4.2. But I've also read that it can't be used in a transaction while I do need this within a transaction. So is there another solution?

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind, I 'm afraid you have to run this in memory